# Coding: Keep track of last N days of records for each user.

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

Im solving an interesting problem wherein for each user, I would like to keep his last N days of activity. This can be applied to many a use-cases and one such simple one is:

For each user - user can come to gym some random day - I want to get the total number of times he hit the gym over the last 90 days.

This is a tricky one for me.

My thoughts: I thought of storing a vector where each entry would determine a day and then a boolean value might represent his visit. To count, just linear processing of that section in the array would suffice.

What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make for every client a [Queue data structu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type))re containing elements with visit date. 
When client visits gym, just add current date

```
Q[ClientIdx].Add(Today)
```

When you need to get a track for him:

```
while (not Q[ClientIdx].Empty) and (Today - Q[ClientIdx].Peek > 90) 
    Q[ClientIdx].Remove  //dequeue too old records
VisitCount = Q.Count
```

You can use standard Queue implementations in many languages or simple own implementation based on array/list if standard one is not available.

Note that every record is added and removed once, so amortized complexity is O(1) per add/count operation

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how complex you need it to be, a simple array that stores each of a clients visits should suffice.

Upon each visit, add a new entry containing the date/time. Each day, run a check to see if any clients contain visit records that are older than 90 days. The first record that is not old enough means there are no more records to check, so you can safely move to the next client.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Your idea will work, but is it really space-wise efficient?

Your [data-structure](/questions/tagged/data-structure) would be something like this: A boolean 2D vector (you can imagine it as a matrix), where every row is a user and every column is a day (sorted), so that would consist of a:

> matrix of size `U x N`

where U is the number of users.

To answer the question I initially asked, you need to think how *dense* this matrix is going to be. If it's going to be much, then you made the right choice, if not, then you wasted (much) space. You can see the trade-off here.

Of course, you have to think about your use case. In the gym example, I do not think this would be space efficient, since most people do not go to the gym every day (I think), which will result in a sparse matrix, meaning that we wasted space.

---

Another idea would be to have a single vector os size `N`, where the days are sorted. Every entry would be a single linked list, where every node would be a user.

If a user is found in the list of a day, then it means that he went to gym at that day.

With this approach we allocate *exactly* as much space as needed, so it's space optimal, regardless of the density I mentioned in the matrix's case.

---

However, is this it? No, of course not! I discussed about space, but what about time efficiency? For example, search is a usually frequent method we want our data structure to support, and if we would like that to be fast!

In the matrix's case, search would be an O(1) operation, which is sweet, since accessing the matrix is a constant operation.

In the vector+list's case however, the search would take O(L), where `L` is the average size of the lists our vector has in total.

---

So which one? It depends on your application!

I would try a hashtable as well, which would not require sorting and is space efficient ([What is the space complexity of a hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529966/what-is-the-space-complexity-of-a-hash-table)).

Comment: how would you check the last 90 days on each visit to gym? for each visit, which might not be every day, I wish to check the last 90 days from that day!

Comment: Since the days are being sorted, you simply scan the rest of them @sad!

Answer (score 0):

How about having an **Queue** with fixed size (90) of visit details for every user? You can generalise it for multiple users and key advantage is you don't have to worry about maintaining last 90 days of data.

You can dump a queue to list or array and persist if needed in O(n). And as you have mentioned the check for no.of presence will be O(n) as well.