# Dictionary memory usage

Tags: c#, dictionary, memory-management

I have been experimenting with memory consumption of different collections lately, and noticed that the Dictionary seems to use a lot of memory.

In the following code, the `Data` `record struct` is 24 bytes, and with 10 million elements, that's around ~240MB of memory.

With the array version, the memory usage is about right, and shows up as around 240MB.

But with the dictionary version, its a whopping 430MB?

Is this to be expected for a dictionary? I appreciate that the collection itself has to allocate memory for the element management algorithm, but is double about right?

I did experiment with garbage collecting as I thought it might just be temporary memory usage, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

And as a follow up question, is there a key/value container (with similar access performance) that has a smaller memory footprint? the key/value collection will be created once, and then read only from that point. I'm thinking the only other option is a sorted array and then simply using a binary search?

```
internal class Program
{
    public record struct Data(double X, double Y, double Z);

    const int Elements = 10_000_000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Array
        //{
        //    var items = new Data[10_000_000];
        //    double sum = 0;
        //    foreach (var item in items)
        //    {
        //        sum += item.X;
        //    }

        //    Console.WriteLine(items.Length);
        //    Console.Read();
        //}

        // Dictionary
        {
            IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Data> items = Enumerable.Range(0, Elements)
                .ToDictionary(k => k, v => new Data(v, v, v));
            
            Console.WriteLine(items.Count);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it can be. dictionaries store things in different buckets based on the hashcode

Comment: _access performance_ is the key to understanding the problem! Dictionary is HashTable that has O(1) complexity. Sorted array is a good choice, but binary search a bit more slowly: O(log n) complexity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13504008/5045688 - Quote: _Lets pretend we have a naive hashtable where the number of buckets is equal to double the size of the elements. That is O(2n) the number of elements which is O(n)._

Comment: Currently your key is just an abitrary continguous int range so an array is the optimum for the "get me the value for this index" case. For better help for an actual non example case we need to know more about the actual key data.

Comment: The key data would indeed be an int. Just not contiguous, so a simple array could not be used. Can you suggest any other types of collections that could be used?

Comment: You have the two prominent options already in here. One more optimized for access (Dictionary) one more optimized for memory usage(Sorted Array/List).  I don't see anything in between that gets you behaviors close two both at the same time.  If you have inner knowledge about the key and its not really random but has a pattern that you can use you might come up with something that replaces storing by hash in the Dictionary with doing the math (key -> index) yourself and getting faster access on a sorted List then binary search.